# setImagePath(String ImagePath) not working in LibGdx ParticleEffect

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to do something like this:

```
`ParticleEffect pe = new ParticleEffect();
if(pe.getEmitters().get(0).isComplete())
{ 
pe.getEmitters().get(0).setImagePath("x4.png");
pe.getEmitters().get(0).start();
}`
```

but the new image does not load, it still shows previous image as declared in .p file. How do I load a new particle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sprite from desired texture and then use `ParticleEmitter.setSprite()` method. This method doesn't have documentation unfortunately. So see source code: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/ParticleEmitter.java#L597